# Doxygen EXTRACT_ALL=NO does not work

Tags: doxygen

I have the following Problem using doxygen in an C project. I have many internal structures that are not documented. Therefore it set `EXTRACT_ALL=NO` in my Doxyfile. Unfortunately doxygen still extracts some of them. Here is a minimal working example. Suppose the following header file:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
# define HASHTABLE_H
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
typedef void* object;
typedef char *(*object_getname)( object obj);
typedef void (*object_free)( object obj);
typedef mess_int_t (*object_hash)( char *name,  mess_int_t size);
typedef struct  {
 hashtable_entry *next;
 object *obj;
} hashtable_entry;
typedef struct {
 object_getname name;
 object_free freigabe;
 object_hash hash;
 mess_int_t size;
 hashtable_entry **hashtable;
} hashtable_t;
typedef hashtable_t * hashtable;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

and the following options set in the Doxyfile:

```
EXTRACT_ALL            = NO
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO 
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = NO
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = NO 
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = NO
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
```

But in the generate Data structure list both structures are listed. Some other undocumented structures defined in the same way in other files are not listed as I expect it from the description of `EXTRACT_ALL=NO`. Why does doxygen extract some and others not?

The whole doxyfile is available at: http://pastebin.com/J7c9BbvW

I am using doxygen 1.8.5

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with 1.8.5, code into file aa.c and standard Doxyfile wit all EXTRACT_... set as indicated, but was not able to reproduce it, in the HTML output I only see an empty main page. Can you share some more information?

Comment: I uploaded the whole doxyfile there: http://pastebin.com/J7c9BbvW for me both structures get visible. Interestingly only structures in *.h files seems to be listed. Internalones in *.c files do not occur in the documentation.

Comment: Even a new generated Doxyfile using `doxygen -g` gives me the same result.

Comment: The problem at my side was that I put the code in a c file instread of a h file.

Comment: To achieve what you want, I think, you have to set: HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = YES and HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = YES

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of the problem is, like we already discussed it in the above comments, that the following setup works:

```
EXPORT_ALL=NO
```

in the `Doxyfile` prevents doxygen only extract data structures from header files instead of all source files.

Setting

```
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES = YES
```

disables the listing of undocumented structures in the header files.

Comment: 'EXPORT_ALL'? Shouldn't that be 'EXTRACT_ALL'?

Answer (score 0):

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = NO
```

Unfortunately, doxygen does not parse multi-including header files protect:

```
#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
# define HASHTABLE_H
```